# MySQL query with reserved keyword and multiple select in MySQL 8.0

Tags: sql, mysql, syntax

I have no clue which one is incorrect with my query:

```
SELECT
rank
FROM
(
SELECT
    @rn := @rn +1 AS rank,
    t1.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        playdata
    WHERE
        game_id = 629 AND recordtime > '2023-02-06 01:44:01' AND domain_id = 46
    ORDER BY
        score
    DESC,
        recordtime ASC
    LIMIT 20
) t1,
(
SELECT
@rn := 0
) t2
) xx WHERE  field_5='8247db4f-0760-4301-8fcb-272808fde877' AND 
YEARWEEK(recordtime)=YEARWEEK(NOW());
```

It said:
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM ( SELECT @rn := @rn +1 AS rank, t1.* FROM ' at line 3`

I have checked the mysql validator, and it's the same. Try to breakdown the syntax, but no clue.
Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are using a version of MySQL in which `rank` is a reserved keyword, then it must be MySQL 8.0. In that case, you should learn about [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), which are standard SQL and easier and more versatile than the old workarounds in MySQL 5.x with user variables.

Comment: i have used MySQL 8.0